# CSS: Absolute(?) positioning skewed element (no JS !important)

Tags: css, transform, skew

Is it possible to absolute position skewed element so its left-bottom corner stay close (0px) to container's border?

```css
#one{
  position:absolute;
  background-color:darkkhaki;
  width:800px;
  height:200px;
  left:50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%)
}

#rect{
  position:absolute;
  background-color: salmon;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  left:50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) skew(-25deg);
}

#marker{
  position:absolute;
  background-color:red;
  width:5px;
  height:200px;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <div id="rect"></div>
  <div id="marker"></div>
  <div>
```

I've marked with red line position of the rectangle side before skewing it. I'm looking for a way to position the rectangle, so its left-bottom corner touches the red line and no JS allowed. 
I cannot simply use 'left: Ypx', because the whole thing is going to be keyframes-animated (changing skew, rotateX + constant perspective on outer element).

Otherwise, maybe you can suggest another way for making animation: the pictures that are slowly 'getting up' from laying-on-the-table position?

edit:
[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpaKmk)

Comment: If anyone had similar problem, found simple solution: "transform-origin: bottom left." on element that is undergoing the transformation (#rect in my example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [transform-origin Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp).
For yours case i put `<div id="marker">` inside `<div id="rect">` and change transform-origin to `0% 100%`.

**Look at my example:**

```css
#one{
  position:absolute;
  background-color:darkkhaki;
  width:800px;
  height:200px;
  left:50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%)
}

#rect{
  position:absolute;
  background-color: salmon;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  left:50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) skew(-25deg);
}

#marker{
  position:absolute;
  background-color:red;
  width:5px;
  height:200px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  transform: skew(25deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 100%;
  transform-origin: 0% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <div id="rect">
     <div id="marker"></div>
  </div>
<div>
```

And this [**Working Fiddle**](https://fiddle.jshell.net/zeevkatz/d8ejzdy9/)

Comment: Found it out 3 mn before you posted your answer (vide: comment above). Nevertheless, that's easy solution and I give you one up. :)